qtdemux qtdemux.c:7423:gst_qtdemux_loop:<qtdemux0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
I am trying to stream a video stored on my system using Gstreamer using Java as a coding language.
This is the pipeline which runs fine when executed on CLI:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=C:\\Users\\Sunder.Kumar\\Downloads\\SampleVideo2.mp4 ! decodebin !
 videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 sync=false

I am trying to convert this into a java program using the gstreamer API which is as follows:
package streaming;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.Element;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.ElementFactory;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.Gst;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.Pipeline;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.Version;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.glib.GLib;
import streaming.utils.Utils;

public class SampleVideoStreamv2 {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SampleVideoStream.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLib.setEnv("GST_DEBUG", "4", true);
        Gst.init(Version.of(1, 16));
        Utils.configurePaths();

        Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline();

        Element fileSrc = ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "file-source");
        fileSrc.set("location", "C:\\\\Users\\\\Sunder.Kumar\\\\Downloads\\\\SampleVideo.mp4");

        Element decodeBin = ElementFactory.make("decodebin", "decoder");
        Element videoConvert = ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "video-convert");
        Element x264Enc = ElementFactory.make("x264enc", "x264-encoder");
        Element rtph264Pay = ElementFactory.make("rtph264pay", "rtp-h264-payload");
        Element udpSink = ElementFactory.make("udpsink", "udp-sink");
        udpSink.set("host", "127.0.0.1");
        udpSink.set("port", 5000);

        pipeline.addMany(fileSrc, decodeBin, videoConvert, x264Enc, rtph264Pay, udpSink);
        
        fileSrc.link(decodeBin);
        decodeBin.link(videoConvert);
        videoConvert.link(x264Enc);
        x264Enc.link(rtph264Pay);
        rtph264Pay.link(udpSink);
        
        pipeline.play();
        Gst.main();
    }

}

The output:

I dont know where I am going wrong.
I was expecting it to work since the element linking correctly corresponds to the pipeline which was run on CLI successfully.
